How can I retrieve my full profile data from LinkedIn using the API? (Apply with LinkedIn)
We would like to enable users to import their LinkedIn profile data into our application.
As a startup, our app has not yet been released.
Is the AWLI Plugin is the solution? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/apply-with-linkedin/awli-plugin
We also read here in the forum that the AWLI Plugin no longer works.
Does anyone have the AWLI plugin that is currently working?
Are there other ways to retrieve the full profile data without being a LinkedIn-partner?
Does anyone have experience with this topic?
Our previous attempts:

Applied for the LinkedIn partner certification -> no response.
Created and verified an app on https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps and tried multiple API products. -> no API available to retrieve the entire user profile.

